# How to translate “lazy initialization”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)

> In computer programming, **lazy initialization** is the tactic of delaying
>   the creation of an object, the calculation of a value, or some other
>   expensive process until the first time it is needed.

So, how would “lazy initialization” or “lazy loading” be translated in French?

I was thinking of something like “*initialisation tardive/paresseuse*”, but I am unsure about this translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, *lazy evaluation* is already called *évaluation paresseuse*, which is a specific case of lazy initialization, so *initialisation paresseuse* seems fine. [French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89valuation_paresseuse) says that you could use *retardée* ("delayed") instead of *paresseuse*, but that word seems used a lot less.

Comment: J'ai une préférence pour _différé_ plutôt que _retardé_.

Comment: **instanciation différée** definintely has my preference. **paresseuse** has a negative connotation ([one of seven deadly sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth_(deadly_sin))) and **retardé** is usually used the same way as in English when referring to a retarded person